Modify and delete tables and apply to DBContext
I had an old bank and store that stored user information and product information in the database.
Now I updated the store and changed many tables
On the other hand, I need to extract the previous information I got and use them.
Now I restored the previous bank.
But when I want to make a new migration, it does not allow me and says that this table already exists in the bank.
enter image description here
What should I do ?????
After several searches for this code
        public  MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    

1 _I have a backup from the previous database
2_It creates the tables but does not replace the information
3_I tried several other ways

Seems you are using code-first Entity Framework design. There should be a table called _MigrationHistories which saves which migration this database has applied. Have you check if the items in that table is the same with your actual migrations in code?

Yes, you are right, I am using the first code of Entity Framework.
My database was for my store that I wrote with Razor Pages.
Now I have rewritten the program with Blazor.
And I want to use my previous information in the web application, but I cannot access the database or change its tables through the code.
Something in the middle prevents this.
When I want to change it or I want to make a new migration
It shows me this error.
linkbold

Do these steps.
1_Remove Migration Folder
2_Remove _MigrationHistory Table Database
3_Add-Migration Clever
4_Just Delete Content Method up
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
  {
      
  }


inside (Do not delete the method itself)


Do not remove the Down method

5_Update-Database
